# Digital Ocean git bare repo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I am trying to setup my own production environment on digital ocean with ubuntu, rails and git.

I have followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-git-hooks-on-ubuntu-14-04) and [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps) tutorial among others.

They all instruct to create the repository as bare, i.e.:

```
mkdir site.git && cd site.git
git init --bare
```

Problem is that when I push from my local computer, I got the error:

> This operation must be run in a work tree

I looked into it and it seems that the cause is that the repo is bare.

In my post receive file I have:

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/home/rails/myapp --git-dir=/var/repo/site.git checkout -f
```

So I am confused. I suppose that I could initialize the repo as non bare instead. But why every tutorial suggests to initialize it as bare if then it causes that error?

Comment: Have you made any commits?

Comment: Those tutorials are effectively creating a git server. You wouldn't push from inside there - that's the place you push *to*. Did you use `--bare` when creating the repo on your local computer? If so, you should not use it there, only in the one place in the tutorial it is used, on the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are making a git push, you must do so from a normal git repo, meaning a local repo on your workstation (pushing indeed to a bare repo)

```
cd /path/to/my/local/repo

git init .
git add -A
git commit -m "my first commit"
git remote add origin /usr/bare/repo
git push -u origin master
```

In your case, you cannot push directly from where the post-receive hook does a checkout, unless you mention in your git push command where the git repo is (bare or not)

```
cd /home/rails/myapp
git --work-tree=/home/rails/myapp --git-dir=/var/repo/site.git push -u origin master
```

(and this assume `/var/repo/site.git` does include a remote named origin)

Comment: Hi, of course i'm pushing from local repo. The setup you suggested is for the local repo which I did already. I can push from ly local computer to heroku. Hence my local git is fine. I used --bare when I created repo on remote server. Now I suspect there is something wrong on the hooks file post-receive. I will keep checking and confirm later

Comment: @Catmal yes, if you have that post-receive hook content, I can check if it allows for pushing.

Comment: Ok addes the content to the question

Comment: I'm getting this error now` refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error: 
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into`

Comment: Before I tried to initialize the git on remote as non bare. Then I tried to intialize it again as --bare. But I'm not sure that was right. Perhaps I should just create a new git on remote server..

Comment: If your post-receive hook does a push, it should do so to another bare repo, with its own post-receive hook to checkout the result.

Comment: Yes I understand that. The problem now is that the repo seems to be not bare. And I'm not sure how to make it bare..

Comment: I can push now. But it gets until `Total 6 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://rails@serverip/var/repo/site.git
   775d3fc..65faa24  master -> master`. It's not deploying the app. Looks like git and app are not connected.

Comment: I marked your answer as accepted anyway as the problem in my question was solved. If you have a quick solution for the app not deploying would be great otherwise I'll make a new question for it in case. Thanks!

Comment: Ok that was stupid mistake I deleted by mistake #!/bin/bash at the beginning of the script when I copied oyur code. All working now!